# R: Passing different-lengthed inputs to purrr with nested data structures

Tags: r, list, mapping, purrr, data-wrangling

I have two lists `foo` and `bar`, where `length(foo) > length(bar)`. I want to apply a function `length(bar)` times to each element of `bar` and store the output of each application in is own list and store all of the applications of the function to each element of `bar` in their own lists. This nested list output structure is important as I am passing it to functions that require nested lists. Examples of what I have and desired are in the minimal example.

While this works nicely with nested for-loops, I've been trying to accomplish this with `purrr`'s `map` functions. I've managed to do this by creating (a) a list of `length(bar)` where each element is `foo`, (b) passing this new list and `bar` to an anonymous function in `purrr::pmap()`, and then (c) passing this to an anonymous function in `purrr:map()`.

While this works, it seems very antithetical to the purpose of `purrr`:

- Instead of `.x`, `.y`, and `~` syntax, I'm defining anonymous functions.
- Instead of passing my raw lists (which vary in length), I'm converting one to a nested list to match the other's length. This can be memory-intensive, slow, etc.
- I'm working with nested lists rather than flatter lists/dataframes I then partition into my desired data structure.

Is there an alternative way of working with different-length lists in `purrr` than my aproach? How might I modify my code (minimal example below) to better-exploit the syntax of `purrr`? One idea ([Handling vectors of different lengths in purrr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43966104/handling-vectors-of-different-lengths-in-purrr)) is to use `cross()` or some equivalent to generate a single object for passing to `pmap()`, but I'm not how how to then generate the nested list structure.

```
library(purrr)

# Example data: 2 different-length lists
foo <- list(1, 2, 3)
bar <- list("df1", "df2")

# Desired output:
out <- list(list("df1_1", "df1_2", "df1_3"),
            list("df2_1", "df2_2", "df2_3"))

# Distinctive features of output:
#length(out) == length(bar)
#length(out[[1]]) == length(out[[2]])
#length(out[[1]]) == length(foo)

# Can use purrr::pmap but this will concurrently
# iterate through each element of inputs ("in
# parallel") so need to create same-length inputs
foo_list <- rep(list(foo), 2)

# Pass our inputs to pmap then use map to iterate
# over foo contained in each foo_list element.
purrr::pmap(list(foo_list, bar),
            function(foo, bar) {
              map(foo, function(i) {
                paste0(bar, "_", i)
              })
            })
```

Comment: Can't you unlist and do this more easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a nested `map`.  Loop over the 'bar' `list`, then do the loop over the 'foo' and `paste`.  This will return a nested `list` as in the OP's expected

```
library(purrr)
out2 <- map(bar, ~ map(foo, function(y) paste0(.x, '_', y)))
identical(out, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Equivalent option in `base R` is

```
lapply(bar, function(x) lapply(foo, function(y) paste0(x, '_', y)))
```

---

Or with `base R`, we could use `outer`, to create a `matrix` of strings, then split by row (`asplit` with `MARGIN` as 1), into a `list` of `vector`s, loop over the `list` and convert each element of the `vector` to a `list` element with `as.list`

```
out3 <- lapply(asplit(outer(bar, paste0('_', foo), FUN = paste0), 1), as.list)
identical(out, out3)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Excellent. The confusing part to me is whether .x refers to the elements of `foo` or the elements of `bar`.  Seems somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: @user3614648 `.x` always returns the elements of the current call.  When we have multiple calls nested, it is better to make use of traditional anonymous function where we have the flexibility to name it as `x` or `y` or any other name to differentiate